# CodeIgniter Project installation error showing "Unauthorized!" on my login page

Tags: php, codeigniter, installation, controller, routes

I recently downloaded a free copy of a school management system built in PHP/CodeIgniter and installed it on my cpanel shared hosting server. I have followed the installation instructions and made the necessary changes to the database and route files but I always get an 'Unauthorized!' error when i load the application in the browser where the login page is supposed to come up.
I am not sure if i am getting the routes wrong because i installed the app into a sub folder in the public_html folder.
Can anyone give me advice on what i may be doing wrong. I have been at it since the past 72 hours. I am now confused as per the routes since the application was not deployed to the root of the domain. Any help will be highly appreciated.

the code below i have been changing with no luck:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'login';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: please read through this: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html

Comment: This hasn't helped. I cannot find the Paths.php file in the application folder. I appreciate the effort but i looked at this document already.

Comment: sorry, link above was for CI 4.x, for CI 3.x see: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/managing_apps.html#relocating-your-application-directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you checked your database.php file

application -> config -> database.php

check the details it should be like this:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'user_name',
    'password' => 'your_password',
    'database' => 'db_name',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: Thanks Umar for your answer

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when installing the same project; the issue came in the **Login** controller. You have to remove the link to install process and make it just connect directly to the database without any effort.

Change the present index function to this;

```
public function index() {
   
   //$results = $this->unlinkInstaller();

    if ($this->session->userdata('admin_login') == 1)
        redirect(base_url() . '/admin/dashboard', 'refresh');

    if ($this->session->userdata('teacher_login') == 1)
        redirect(base_url() . '/teacher/dashboard', 'refresh');
        
    if ($this->session->userdata('librarian_login') == 1)
        redirect(base_url() . '/librarian/dashboard', 'refresh');
        
        if ($this->session->userdata('accountant_login') == 1)
        redirect(base_url() . '/accountant/dashboard', 'refresh');
        
        if ($this->session->userdata('hostel_login') == 1)
        redirect(base_url() . '/hostel/dashboard', 'refresh');

    if ($this->session->userdata('student_login') == 1)
        redirect(base_url() . '/student/dashboard', 'refresh');

    if ($this->session->userdata('parent_login') == 1)
        redirect(base_url() . '/parents/dashboard', 'refresh');

    // if ($results['RESULT'] == 'INVALID' || $results['RESULT'] == 'EMPTY' || $results['RESULT'] == 'INVALID_DOMAIN') {
    //     $this->load->view('backend/error');
    // } else {
    //     $this->load->view('backend/login');
    // }

    $this->load->view('backend/login');
}
```

You can see that I just commented the first line to avoid going through installation process.

//$results = $this->unlinkInstaller();

Hope it still usefull.